# Read number from file

Tags: conditionals, filesystem-access

I have a file called `_runs.ini`. Depending on its content, the document is compiled differently. I tried to read the content and executed a `\ifthenelse`-command without success.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\getrun{%
    \newread\tmp
    \openin\tmp=_runs.ini
    \read\tmp to \pruns
    \def\ppruns{\numexpr \pruns\relax}
    \closein\tmp
}

\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\ppruns}{0}}
        {true}{false}
}

\begin{document}

\getrun
\startrun

\end{document}
```

The content of `_runs.ini` is `0` but obvisously the `\equal`-command does not recognize it as `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And an answer with the original `\ifthenelse`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\getrun{%
    \newread\tmp
    \openin\tmp=_runs.ini
    \read\tmp to \pruns
    \def\ppruns{\numexpr \pruns\relax}
    \closein\tmp
}

\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\pruns}{0 }}%<-- space!
        {true}{false}
}

\newcommand\startrunb{%
  \ifthenelse{\ppruns=0}
        {true}{false}
}

\begin{document}

\getrun
\startrun

\startrunb
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're sure the file contains a number, I recommend a simpler strategy.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newread\tmp
\newcommand\getrun{%
  \openin\tmp=_runs.ini
  \read\tmp to \pruns
  \closein\tmp
}

\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifnum\pruns=0
    true
  \else
    false
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\getrun
\startrun

\end{document}
```

Or, with `catchfile`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\run}{%
  \CatchFileDef{\pruns}{_runs.ini}{}%
  \ifnum\pruns=0
     true
  \else
     false
  \fi
}
```

You can also use `ifthen`, if you like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newread\tmp
\newcommand\getrun{%
  \openin\tmp=_runs.ini
  \read\tmp to \pruns
  \closein\tmp
}

\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifthenelse{\pruns=0}{true}{false}
}

\begin{document}

\getrun
\startrun

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer, using `readarray` package, is set up to discern whether the lone character of the file is a "0" or not.  If you need a more intricate test (i.e., if the file can be more than a single character), let me know the specifics.

The `\readdef` command places the file contents into a `\def`, which I then can compare directly with an `\if` (here I assume the file is a single character).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcommand\getrun{\readdef{_runs.ini}{\mydata}}
\newcommand\startrun{\if0\mydata true\else false\fi}
\begin{document}
\getrun
\startrun
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE is a composite of various mistakes.

**First.** Numbers can be compared by num=num. The `\equal` from `ifthen.sty` package compares strings (after expansion), no numbers.

**Second.** OK, you are using `\equal` and you have the problem that the `\pruns` macro includes `"0 "` (zero space) and you compare it with `"0"` (zero). These two strings are not equal. The space is here from the end of line in the external file, i.e from `\endlinechar`. Maybe this is a reason why you added new complication to your code: the new macro `\ppruns`.

**Third.** Macro `\ppruns` is able to remove this trailing space (using eTeXs command `\numexpr`) but you forgot the `\the` before `\numexpr`. Your definition of `\ppruns` expands to `\numexpr 0 \relax` this is not the same as `0`. If you add the `\the` before `\numexpr` then `\ppruns` expands to `0` which is desired. But it is clear that your attempt is very unclear and the superfluous functionality of eTeX is used here.

Simple solution is: compare numbers no strings, don't use superfluous `\ppruns`:

```
\ifnum\pruns=0 true\else false\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot `\ppruns`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifnumcomp{\pruns}{=}{0}{true}{false}
}
```

Or better (plain TeX!):

```
\newcommand\startrun{%
  \ifnum\pruns=0
    true
  \else
    false
  \fi
}
```

Comment: @egreg answered with plain TeX version while I was editing, sorry.

Comment: This is not exactly plain TeX. The `\newcommand` is unknown in plain TeX.

Comment: I mean the body of `\newcommand` is plain TeX, obviously not the `\newcommand` itself.