# Counting chars + spaces in mainmatter and appendix files

Tags: texcount

I am trying to make an automatic char count with spaces on my report, so that i get a char count on my main mainmatter displayed and one on my appendix. I have looked at Paul Gessler answer
([Command for character count including spaces (in overleaf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470709/command-for-character-count-including-spaces-in-overleaf)) but i can't get it to work if i have more files then the main.tex.

So far i have tried just to count the main.tex file but it comes up with an error "Missing number, treated as zero."

```
% ~~~~~~~~~~~
% Mainmatter - Chapters
% ~~~~~~~~~~~

\mainmatter

\quickwordcount{main}
\quickcharcount{main}

There are \thechar characters and approximately \theword spaces.
That makes approximately \the\numexpr\theword+\thechar\relax\ characters total.


\include{Chapters/1. INDLEDNING}

\include{Chapters/2. PROBLEMFORMULERING}

\include{Chapters/3. TEORI OG METODE}

\include{Chapters/4. PROJEKTRESULTATER}

\include{Chapters/5. DISKUSSION}

\include{Chapters/6. KONKLUSION}


% ~~~~~~~~~~~
% appendix, billag og referancer
% ~~~~~~~~~~~


\pagestyle{empty}
\appendix
  
\include{App, Bil, Bib/appendix}          % Appendix A
```

In my preamble which is put in with \input{preamble} in the beginning i have

```
 \newread\tmp

\newcommand{\quickcharcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge -char #1.tex > #1-chars.sum}%
  \openin\tmp=#1-chars.sum%
  \read\tmp to \thechar%
  \closein\tmp%
}

\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex > #1-words.sum}%
  \openin\tmp=#1-words.sum%
  \read\tmp to \theword%
  \closein\tmp%
 }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You should check the contents of the two `.sum` files to see what they contain: each should contain just a single number. However, if `texcount` produced an error message, the values returned would not be a number which could explain the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i made the code a bit shorter
```
\immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -relaxed -merge  main.tex  > word.sum}
\newcommand\wordcount{\input{word.sum}}
\immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -relaxed -char -merge  main.tex > char.sum}
\newcommand\charcount{\input{char.sum}}
```

```
There are \charcount characters and \\
approximately \wordcount spaces. \\
total \\
\the\numexpr\charcount+\wordcount\relax
```
But it seems like it wont treat  ` \charcount` and `\wordcount` like a number that i can add togeather even through they show as numbers above.

Comment: sorry i am not sure hout to check the contents of the two `.sum` files.